# How can one share the code between tests and benches in Rust?

Tags: testing, rust, benchmarking, source-sets

I started writing benchmarks in Rust with "bench" and Rust nightly as written in the docs.

In order to share the code between test and benchmarks i've added `Option<&mut Bencher>` and either run the code block directly or with bencher passed ("src/lib.rs"):

```
fn block_requests(bencher_option: Option<&mut Bencher>, ...) {
    ...

    let mut block = || {
       ... // shared
    }

    match bencher_option {
            // regular test
            None => block(),

            // benchmark
            Some(bencher) => {
                bencher.iter(block);
            }
        }
    ...
}

// call from test
#[test]
fn test_smth() {
    block_requests(None, &requests, &mut matcher);
}


// call from benchmark
#[bench]
fn bench_smth(b: &mut Bencher) {
    block_requests(Some(b), &requests, &mut matcher);
}
```

Now i want to use Rust **stable** for benchmarks.
Since ["bencher" crate](https://crates.io/crates/bencher) is not updated for 3 years it seems that ["criterion" crate](https://crates.io/crates/criterion) is the default option. For this i have to move the code to "./benches/my_benchmark.rs".

How can i still share the `block_requests(..)` between the tests and benchmarks?

Comment: `use mycrate::block_requests`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tests/` and `benches/` work the same way as `src/main.rs` or `src/bin/*.rs`: they are *separate binary crates.* This means that they must refer to items in your library crate by name, and those items must be *visible.*

So, you need to change

```rust
fn block_requests(bencher_option: Option<&mut Bencher>, ...) {
```

to make it `pub`lic, and you will probably also want to add `#[doc(hidden)]` so that your library documentation does not contain testing helpers:

```rust
#[doc(hidden)]
pub fn block_requests(bencher_option: Option<&mut Bencher>, ...) {
```

Then, in your tests and benchmarks, `use` it *by giving the name of your crate.*

```
use my_library_crate_name::block_requests;

fn bench_smth(...) {...}
```

(You cannot use `use crate::block_requests` here because the keyword `crate` refers to the benchmark binary crate, not the library crate.)